# Filter request code handler

Tags: java, beginner, http, concurrency, servlets

I use the following code which works OK, the code is filtering requests and in case there are too many requests it sends some logs/errors
since I'm very new to Java my question if there is a better way to write it especially the while statement ...

```
 public final class filterBu implements Filter {

        private static AtomicInteger reqcnt;
        private static final String MAX_CUNCCURENT = "maxConcurrent";
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContentValidationFilter.class);
        private static final String EXCEED_MAX_REQUESTS_MSG = "maximum reaced";
        private static int maxCunnccurent;
        private static final int TOO_MANY_REQUESTS = 429;


        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            while (true) {
                int value = reqcnt.get();
                if (value >= maxCunnccurent) {
                    ((HttpServletResponse) resp).sendError(TOO_MANY_REQUESTS, EXCEED_MAX_REQUESTS_MSG);
                    return;
                }
                if (reqcnt.compareAndSet(value, value + 1)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                chain.doFilter(req, resp);
            } finally {
                reqcnt.decrementAndGet();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException, NumberFormatException {
            maxCunnccurent = Integer.parseInt(config.getInitParameter(MAX_CUNCCURENT));
            if (maxCunnccurent < 1) {
                logger.error("excced limit"); 
            }
            reqcnt = new AtomicInteger(0);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `AtomicInteger` with a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) holding `maxCunnccurent` (maxConcurrent, right?) permits. So :

```
reqcnt = new Semaphore(maxCunnccurent);
```

Now, each time you get a filter request, you try to get a permit. If you do get a permit, you go ahead and filter, making sure that afterwards you release the permit again. If you don't get a permit, you send your error response :

```
boolean acquired = reqcnt.tryAcquire();
if (!acquired) {
    ((HttpServletResponse) resp).sendError(TOO_MANY_REQUESTS, EXCEED_MAX_REQUESTS_MSG);
    return;
}
try {
    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
} finally {
    reqcnt.release();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! why the semaphore is better then atomic in this case , not sure that I fully got it, can you please explain...

Comment: Semaphore is just a more natural fit, and it does some of the work you need to do to manage the count for you. As yu can see, it simplifies the code for managing the maximum number of threads. Semaphore is an abstraction over a logical amount of permits, you want to permit only a maximum number of Threads to simultaneously filter.

Comment: One last question :) , you remove the if in your example if  (value >= maxCunnccurent) {  why ? I just want to verify that I didn't exceed the limit...

Comment: The Semaphore checks it for you, if all permits are out, it won't give any more until one is released.

Answer (score 3):

```
public final class filterBu implements Filter {
```

In Java, class names start with a capital letter. It should be `FilterBu` instead of `filterBu`.

What does `Bu` mean? Choose a proper name for your classes. Don't be disappointed if your first name choice is not perfect yet, since [choosing good names is difficult](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html). But you can surely find a better name than `Bu`.

```
    private static AtomicInteger reqcnt;
```

This variable must not be `static`. Imagine you had 17 instances of this filter class. How many counters should you have, 1 or 17? If your answer is 17, remove the `static`.

```
    private static final String MAX_CUNCCURENT = "maxConcurrent";
```

You should run your code through a spell checker, since you make many typos. This one should be `concurrent`. And even if you make spelling mistakes, you should at least be consistent. The name of this constant and its value must match.

```
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContentValidationFilter.class);
```

A `static` logger should always be defined with the enclosing class as argument. Imagine you get a log message saying it's from `ContentValidationFilter`. Where would you suspect it -- in the `ContentValidationFilter` class, or in the completely unrelated `filterBu` class?

```
    private static final String EXCEED_MAX_REQUESTS_MSG = "maximum reaced";
```

It's `reached`.

```
    private static int maxCunnccurent;
```

Another variation on `concurrent`.

```
    private static final int TOO_MANY_REQUESTS = 429;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException, NumberFormatException {
```

You don't need to declare these exceptions to be thrown, for two different reasons. The `ServletException` is never thrown by your code, while the `NumberFormatException` is a `RuntimeException`, which doesn't have to be declared.

```
        maxCunnccurent = Integer.parseInt(config.getInitParameter(MAX_CUNCCURENT));
        if (maxCunnccurent < 1) {
            logger.error("excced limit");
```

Another variation on `limit exceeded`. Furthermore, the error message is misleading, since there is no limit that could be exceeded. This one should rather say `logger.error("Invalid value for maxConcurrent: {}", maxConcurrent)`.

But you should not log anything here at all. Just throw an exception. Because when you don't, `maxConcurrent` will be initialized to 0, allowing 0 concurrent connections. This in turn means that *every* connection attempt will get a 429 error. In such a case it is better to have an exception stack trace in the log file instead of nothing.

```
        }
        reqcnt = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot roland for this elaborating , two question ? should I change the while loop to something better (more safe) if yes how ?2 . you write "there is no limit that could be exceeded." why you think so? what I miss here ? :)

Comment: Regarding the `while` loop: yes, you should change it as suggested in bowmore's answer. My answer is intended as complementary to that answer. Regarding the limit: the word exceeded means "more than allowed", which sounds wrong in a check for negative numbers. Also, a limit usually means an "upper limit", unless it is explicitly called a "lower limit".